# A tcp based client-server system using ns3

Tags: networking, tcp, simulation, ns-3

I am completely new to ns3. All the tutorials that are given in the repo mainly consist of echo servers where they are sending a packet of specific size and receiving the echo. I want to design a real world scenario where the server offers some service. e.g. the client node takes a string in lower case as input and sends to server. The server changes it to upper case and returns to client and client prints it on console. How to model this exact situation in ns3 ? I could not get any solution even after searching for a lot of time and I am not getting any way of actually interacting with the user in ns3.

Comment: May be ask at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very general and cannot be answered in a few lines. You can find the ns3 repository here [LoRaWAN ns-3 module](https://github.com/signetlabdei/lorawan). It contains end devices, a gateway, and a server. A server is responsible for interacting with end devices in many ways. For example, the network server can control the end device's data rate, transmit power, and bandwidth. It also notifies end devices with downlink acknowledgment through a gateway. Based on my opinion, this module can be helpful for your mentioned scenario. If you do not want to violate the tcp/ip protocol stack you should modify the MAC commands used in this module to fulfill your needs.